# Why are there only 2 moderator positions available?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

We've had 3 moderators all this time.  Now, on the moderator election page, I see:

> moderator positions available
>
> 2

Are any of the current moderators keeping their post and we're only replacing others?  Are we simply adding 2 new moderators to the current group?  Are we only going to have 2 moderators going forward?

Comment: [This has been discussed on chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/440772#440772)

Comment: I'd post an answer, but @badp links the chat notes and I'd rather wait until we had an official confirmation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it was changed - the election page now reads:

> **moderator positions available:**
>
> 3

And yes, the team [explicitly stated](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/) that pro-tem mods will not remain mods (unless they win the elections).

Answer (score 5):

To answer the questions I can answer:

- Pro-tempore mods (Juan, Grace and Oak) will *stop* serving as elections end, unless elected.
- Elected moderators are permanent and serve until they step down.

So yes, if nothing changes we will only get to have *two* moderators.